# Which method is more efficient and better to do this task, also why? Please guide

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement, list-comprehension

> Method A : In this method I have performed decision making without converting the 'line' from a string to list.

```
def isVariable(line):
    if not ';' in line:
        return False

    if ('public' in line or 'private' in line or 'protected' in line) and ('int' in line or 'String' in line or 'float' in line):
        return True
    else:
        return False


line = 'private int name;'
print(isVariable(line))
```

> Method B : This method involves performing decision making after converting the 'line' to a list.

```
def isVariable(line):
    if not ';' in line:
        return False

    modifiers = ['private','protected','public']
    datatypes = ['int','float','String']
    linelist = list(line.split())

    if linelist[0] in modifiers and linelist[1] in datatypes:
        return True
    else:
        return False

line = 'private int name;'
print(isVariable(line))
```

Comment: Only second variant ensures that keywords are whole words. First method would find e.g.`private` in `private_value`

Comment: Did you try profiling your code? Note, `isVariable` would be faster if you didn't create the lists every function call, rather, reference some global constants, maybe use a `set` instead of lists (although, for something this small, it does'n't really matter

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga very helpful ! :)

Comment: @MichaelButscher what you mean by 'private in private_value'?

Comment: The second answer will parse the line less times. It only goes through the whole line once to split it into words. In the later checks it only has to look at the appropriate word and check it. Again more efficient. Added benefit is that it ensures they are in the right places in the line and as was pointed out by @MichaelButscher it also ensures they are full not partial matches. So from both performance and accuracy, the second is better.

Comment: The expression `'private' in 'private_value'` is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most efficient way to do this would be

```
import re

def isVariable(line):
    return re.fullmatch('(private|protected|public) (int|float|string) [a-zA-Z_]+;', line)

line = 'private int name;'
print(isVariable(line))
```

Comment: This is good but should probably be more flexible with the amount of whitespace it allows. Also might be better to build a compiled pattern outside the function one time and use that inside the function.

Comment: @GlennMackintosh your solution is definitely flexible but in this task we are not allowed to use in-built functions.

Comment: @RabiSiddique it is not my answer, it is MerlinKatz good answer. I just made a comment on his answer.